# Split CSV String

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, csv, split

How would I split the following string?

```
test, 7535, '1,830,000', '5,000,000'
```

The result should be

```
test
7535
'1,830,000'
'5,000,000'
```

I try:

```
Dim S() as string = mystring.split(",")
```

But I get,

```
test
7535
'1
830
000'
'5
000
000'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't parse CSV manually when you have handy [good quality libraries available](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx). Please!

CSV parsing has many many potential pitfalls and this library, according to my testing, solves most of them neatly.

That said, if this is a one off task and the strings are always like your example, you can use regex, like this (VB.NET syntax might be wrong, please fix):

```
        Dim s as string = "1, 2, '1,233,333', '8,444,555'";
        Dim r as Regex = new Regex(",\s");
        Dim re() as string = r.Split(s);
```

This counts on that there is always a space after the separating comma and that there is no space in the commas between the numbers. If that's not always the case you can:

- Make the regex more complex (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809156/net-system-outofmemoryexception-on-string-split-of-120-mb-csv-file) to see how messy things could get)
- Use the library and be happier

Comment: I disagree about the need to necessarily use a CSV library. If you know the CSV file is well-formatted, then a simple method using ReadLine and Split will do the job perfectly well.

Comment: However, in this situation it is indeed advisable, given that there are comma-delimited numbers in fields.

Comment: So, in other words, you are saying you completely  agree with me :)

Comment: Great pair programming guys :)

Comment: You're assuming the OP is parsing a file's worth of CSV. Taking a dependence on a CSV parsing library would certainly be overkill to split a string (which is what was asked).

Comment: @Mark: I agree, and is one of the meanings I meant with 'a one off task' (third paragrah). Because it seems to me very likely he's actually parsing a CSV file instead of only one string I added the warning. Additionally, this library is very small and efficient so it's not a big concern.

Comment: This is crazy. Why not use the built in [TextParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

If just for this example, no need to use regexp, the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28VS.80%29.aspx)-function (Member of Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings) can take a string as delimeter, so just enter ", " to catch only those commas with space after:

```
    Dim s As String = "1, 2, '1,233,333', '8,444,555'"
    Dim r() As String = Split(s, ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim words as New List(Of String)()
Dim inQuotes as Boolean
Dim thisWord as String
For Each c as Char in String
    If c = "'"c Then inQuotes = Not inQuotes
    If c = ","c AndAlso Not inQuotes Then
        words.Add(thisWord)
        thisWord = Nothing
    Else
        thisWord &= c
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this RegExp: `"('([^']|'')*'|[^',\r\n]*)(,|\r\n?|\n)?"`